# testPreconditions for EditText hint field

Tags: android, testing, junit, unit-testing

I am trying to test that my EditText hint field is not null in junit's

```
testPreconditions()
```

There are examples online for asserting that a TextView is not null, but using EditText in the following way

```
private EditText editTextField;

public void testPreconditions() {
    assertNotNull(editTextField);
}
```

does not work (tests fail).

How do I access the android:hint field of EditText in the assert?

And while this question targets the hint field, answers that also work for similar situations (text of a button, title / elements of a spinner, etc) would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get hint from `EditText` use [`getHint`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getHint%28%29) function.

But it looks like your problem is different. Your test fails because your `editTextField` is null. You should read ["Activity Testing"](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/activity_test.html) article. Shortly, JUnit is not enough, you need to setup a special Android Test project in order to access UI views of `Activity` under test.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for not null of hint you can use the following code

```
EditText et = new EditText(this);
if((et.getHint().toString() != null) && (et.getHint().toString().trim().length()>0)){

}
```